# Why these two GPU kernel have massive performance difference?

Tags: cuda

Hi I am trying to understand some behavior of cuda kernel. These are two cuda kernels I have. I found that `gpuReduce` require two times more duration than `gpuReduceOpt`. Is it caused by divergence?

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>

void initData_int(int *p, int size){
    for (int t=0; t<size; t++){
        p[t] = (int)(rand()&0xff);
    }
}


__global__ void gpuReduce(int *in, int *out, int size)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int* data = in + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (tid >= size)
        return;

    for (int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride*=2)
    {
        if((tid%(2*stride)) == 0){
            data[tid] += data[tid+stride];
            
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (tid == 0){
        out[blockIdx.x] = data[0];
    }
}

__global__ void gpuReduceOpt(int *in, int *out, int size)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int* data = in + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (tid >= size)
        return;
        
    for (int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride*=2)
    {
        int index = 2*stride*tid;
        if(index < blockDim.x){
            data[index] += data[index+stride];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (tid == 0){
        out[blockIdx.x] = data[0];
    }
}

int main(int agrc, char **argv)
{
    int size = 1<<24;
    int blocksize = 1024;

    
    dim3 block(blocksize, 1);
    dim3 grid((size-1)/block.x+1, 1);
    int nBytes = sizeof(int)*size;

    int *a_h = (int*)malloc(nBytes);
    int *tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*grid.x);
    int *tmp1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*grid.x);
    initData_int(a_h, size);

    int *a_d, *output;
    cudaMalloc((int**)&a_d, nBytes);
    cudaMalloc((int**)&output, grid.x*sizeof(int));

    int *a_d1, *output1;
    cudaMalloc((int**)&a_d1, nBytes);
    cudaMalloc((int**)&output1, grid.x*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(a_d1, a_h, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    

    auto start2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    gpuReduce<<<grid, block>>>(a_d, output, size);
    cudaMemcpy(tmp, output, grid.x*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    int gpu_result;

    for (int i =0; i < grid.x; i++)
    {
        gpu_result += tmp[i];
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto end2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double>diff2 = end2 - start2;
    printf("Gpu reduce take:%2f s\n", diff2.count());
    
    auto start3 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    gpuReduceOpt<<<grid, block>>>(a_d1, output1, size);
    cudaMemcpy(tmp1, output1, grid.x*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    int gpu_result1;

    for (int i =0; i < grid.x; i++)
    {
        gpu_result1 += tmp1[i];
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto end3 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double>diff3 = end3 - start3;
    printf("Gpu reduce opt take:%2f s\n", diff3.count());
    printf("Result from gpuReduce and gpuReduceOpt are %6d and %6d\n", gpu_result, gpu_result1);


    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaFree(output);
    free(a_h);
    free(tmp);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the perf data i got:

```
Gpu reduce take:0.004238 s
Gpu reduce opt take:0.002606 s
Result from gpuReduce and gpuReduceOpt are 2139353471 and 2139353471
```

Comment: Both of those kernels contain undefined behaviour, and you haven't explained anything about how you compiled, ran, and benchmarked than, so it is impossible to say why. A guess would be the integer modulo operator. But that's a guess

Comment: I attached the complete program I use. I ran it on 2080 ti GPU.

Comment: Your kernel timings include memory transfer and host operations. You have not measured the *kernels* to know what their performance is. And never benchmark  by running once. Run multiple times (ideally a couple of wall clock seconds of execution), discarding the first call and average because that can include runtime overhead that happens the first time code is run on the GPU, and things like frame refreshing the display can effect single timings if you are using a display GPU

Comment: If you want to do a *fair comparison* between a CPU and a GPU, please use a parallel CPU implementation. This is quite easy to do with OpenMP. I expect a good CPU implementation to beat any GPU implementation if the transfer time is included in the timings.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for your suggestion. But here I only care about comparison between ```gpuReduce``` and ```gpuReduceOpt```.

Comment: Then remove the things that you are not interested in, that's part of creating a [mcve].  Also, your code as posted will not compile.  Also, your `gpuReduce` and `gpuReduceOpt` do not produce the same result so why bother comparing them? `gpuReduceOpt` is broken, if you intended it to produce the same result as your other 2 reductions.  If you're interested in a fast parallel reduction, neither of these sweep schemes is recommended. Use the one provided in the [canonical training](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).

Comment: Hi Robert. I removed unrelated code. And I did verify that results from ```gpuReduce``` and ```gpuReduceOpt``` are the same. And yes, I also implemented another interleaved reduction, which is much faster. I am just curious about the perf improvement source about the above two kernels.

Comment: The first use a slow modulus while the second do not. Memory accesses also matters (I am not just they are similar). Note that strided access are generally slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you now have posted there is still a bug in the host code.  This construct is not correct:

```
int gpu_result;   // not initialized

for (int i =0; i < grid.x; i++)
{
    gpu_result += tmp[i];
}
```

That is undefined behavior.  There is no guarantee the variable `gpu_result` above will start out at zero.  The same problem exists on `gpu_result1`.

When we fix that issue, the difference in kernel time execution mostly comes down to the usage of the modulo operator in the first kernel, as suggested by @talonmies in the first comment.  If you profile each kernel, let's say with `nvprof`, and you ask for metrics like `gld_efficiency`, `gst_efficiency`, `gld_transactions`, and `gst_transactions` you will find that they are all basically identical between the two kernels.

However if you replace the modulo operator with equivalent but less costly arithmetic, the kernel durations become almost the same (to within about 10%):

```
$ cat t1878a.cu
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>

void initData_int(int *p, int size){
    for (int t=0; t<size; t++){
        p[t] = (int)(rand()&0xff);
    }
}


__global__ void gpuReduce(int *in, int *out, int size)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int* data = in + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (tid >= size)
        return;

    for (int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride*=2)
    {
#ifdef USE_FAST
        if((tid&(2*stride-1)) == 0){
#else
        if((tid%(2*stride)) == 0){
#endif
            data[tid] += data[tid+stride];

        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (tid == 0){
        out[blockIdx.x] = data[0];
    }
}

__global__ void gpuReduceOpt(int *in, int *out, int size)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int* data = in + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (tid >= size)
        return;

    for (int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride*=2)
    {
        int index = 2*stride*tid;
        if(index < blockDim.x){
            data[index] += data[index+stride];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if (tid == 0){
        out[blockIdx.x] = data[0];
    }
}

int main(int agrc, char **argv)
{
    int size = 1<<24;
    int blocksize = 1024;


    dim3 block(blocksize, 1);
    dim3 grid((size-1)/block.x+1, 1);
    int nBytes = sizeof(int)*size;

    int *a_h = (int*)malloc(nBytes);
    int *tmp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*grid.x);
    int *tmp1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*grid.x);
    initData_int(a_h, size);

    int *a_d, *output;
    cudaMalloc((int**)&a_d, nBytes);
    cudaMalloc((int**)&output, grid.x*sizeof(int));

    int *a_d1, *output1;
    cudaMalloc((int**)&a_d1, nBytes);
    cudaMalloc((int**)&output1, grid.x*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(a_d1, a_h, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, nBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    auto start2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    gpuReduce<<<grid, block>>>(a_d, output, size);
    cudaMemcpy(tmp, output, grid.x*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    int gpu_result = 0;

    for (int i =0; i < grid.x; i++)
    {
        gpu_result += tmp[i];
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto end2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double>diff2 = end2 - start2;
    printf("Gpu reduce take:%2f s\n", diff2.count());

    auto start3 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    gpuReduceOpt<<<grid, block>>>(a_d1, output1, size);
    cudaMemcpy(tmp1, output1, grid.x*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    int gpu_result1 = 0;

    for (int i =0; i < grid.x; i++)
    {
        gpu_result1 += tmp1[i];
    }
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    auto end3 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double>diff3 = end3 - start3;
    printf("Gpu reduce opt take:%2f s\n", diff3.count());
    printf("Result from gpuReduce and gpuReduceOpt are %6d and %6d\n", gpu_result, gpu_result1);


    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaFree(output);
    free(a_h);
    free(tmp);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1878a t1878a.cu -arch=sm_70 -lineinfo
$ nvprof ./t1878a
==14339== NVPROF is profiling process 14339, command: ./t1878a
Gpu reduce take:0.001021 s
Gpu reduce opt take:0.000543 s
Result from gpuReduce and gpuReduceOpt are 2139353471 and 2139353471
==14339== Profiling application: ./t1878a
==14339== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   97.40%  43.743ms         2  21.872ms  21.280ms  22.463ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
                    1.72%  770.61us         1  770.61us  770.61us  770.61us  gpuReduce(int*, int*, int)
                    0.86%  384.30us         1  384.30us  384.30us  384.30us  gpuReduceOpt(int*, int*, int)
                    0.03%  12.960us         2  6.4800us  6.4000us  6.5600us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
      API calls:   69.86%  350.40ms         4  87.601ms  8.0580us  349.79ms  cudaMalloc
                   19.33%  96.969ms         1  96.969ms  96.969ms  96.969ms  cudaDeviceReset
                    9.13%  45.770ms         4  11.442ms  451.76us  22.822ms  cudaMemcpy
                    1.00%  5.0119ms         4  1.2530ms  590.62us  3.2115ms  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.50%  2.5242ms       404  6.2470us     427ns  270.20us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.09%  449.28us         2  224.64us  10.437us  438.85us  cudaFree
                    0.06%  279.02us         4  69.755us  59.853us  94.003us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.02%  101.11us         2  50.555us  23.936us  77.175us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.00%  22.146us         4  5.5360us  3.2730us  10.770us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  14.686us         2  7.3430us  4.1300us  10.556us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.00%  11.444us         8  1.4300us     506ns  4.8200us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  6.2180us         3  2.0720us     610ns  3.9200us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  3.5570us         4     889ns     740ns  1.1270us  cuDeviceGetUuid
$ nvcc -o t1878a t1878a.cu -arch=sm_70 -lineinfo -DUSE_FAST
$ nvprof ./t1878a
==14375== NVPROF is profiling process 14375, command: ./t1878a
Gpu reduce take:0.000656 s
Gpu reduce opt take:0.000538 s
Result from gpuReduce and gpuReduceOpt are 2139353471 and 2139353471
==14375== Profiling application: ./t1878a
==14375== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   97.92%  38.947ms         2  19.474ms  19.460ms  19.488ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
                    1.08%  427.79us         1  427.79us  427.79us  427.79us  gpuReduce(int*, int*, int)
                    0.97%  385.99us         1  385.99us  385.99us  385.99us  gpuReduceOpt(int*, int*, int)
                    0.03%  13.216us         2  6.6080us  6.4320us  6.7840us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
      API calls:   67.47%  281.96ms         4  70.491ms  5.5820us  281.49ms  cudaMalloc
                   20.44%  85.428ms         1  85.428ms  85.428ms  85.428ms  cudaDeviceReset
                    9.70%  40.518ms         4  10.129ms  457.52us  19.781ms  cudaMemcpy
                    1.20%  5.0260ms         4  1.2565ms  601.24us  3.2163ms  cuDeviceTotalMem
                    0.94%  3.9413ms       404  9.7550us     270ns  1.7028ms  cuDeviceGetAttribute
                    0.10%  435.98us         2  217.99us  9.5230us  426.46us  cudaFree
                    0.10%  410.88us         4  102.72us  58.347us  225.92us  cuDeviceGetName
                    0.02%  94.871us         2  47.435us  20.952us  73.919us  cudaLaunchKernel
                    0.01%  21.734us         4  5.4330us  3.5080us  8.4130us  cuDeviceGetPCIBusId
                    0.00%  14.504us         2  7.2520us  3.8730us  10.631us  cudaDeviceSynchronize
                    0.00%  12.843us         8  1.6050us     460ns  5.3730us  cuDeviceGet
                    0.00%  9.7040us         3  3.2340us     804ns  6.9430us  cuDeviceGetCount
                    0.00%  2.5870us         4     646ns     517ns     957ns  cuDeviceGetUuid
$
```

Notes:

- I'm not suggesting the above is a general replacement for modulo.  It works in this case because `stride` is taking on powers of 2 only.
- I doubt this is doing what you think:

  ```
  if (tid >= size)
      return;
  ```

  but for the problem size here (a whole number multiple of the block size) its not particularly relevant.  It's also not an appropriate choice if the remaining kernel code uses `__syncthreads()` but again that's irrelevant here for this problem size/choice.
- Your code on 2080 Ti is running about 5x slower than on my V100, which doesn't sound right to me.  I wonder if you are building a debug project.  But that doesn't change the observation here.  In case you are building a debug project or with the `-G` compilation switch, I recommend to *never* do performance analysis on debug code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. After removing ```-G```, now the execution time is ```Gpureduce take:0.001334 s``` and ```Gpureduceopt take:0.000734 s```, which are close to perf data from v100 i think. I just knew that  modulo operator could cause such high overhead. Is there any common way to avoid these operations?

Comment: no, there is no magical replacement for modulo that works for every imaginable case.  If there were a common way to reduce the cost, the compiler engineers would have already used that. And modulo like this is certainly not needed in a reduction kernel. You're just exploring various things that are all the wrong ways to do reductions. Nobody should be doing reductions in global memory, for example. I already pointed out to you [the canonical material](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf), and you said: "I am just curious about ... the above two kernels "